# Localstorage to multiple fields in a editable document

Tags: javascript, local-storage, contenteditable

I have a locally ran HTML/CSS/Jquery webpage I am using for a project.

I am trying to implement two things I just learned into it, namely making all of the text areas on the page editable to those to access it, and then trying to get localstorage to save the edits for those who edit.

This is a snippet of what I have, (the remainder is just a continuation of rows and columns): This is the HTML that also makes it editable (this works)

```
<div id="columns">

    <ul id="column1" class="column">
        <li class="widget color-red" contenteditable="true">  
            <div class="widget-head" id="persisted-text">
                <h3>Widget title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aliquam magna sem, fringilla in, commodo a, rutrum ut, massa. Donec id nibh eu dui auctor tempor. Morbi laoreet eleifend dolor. Suspendisse pede odio, accumsan vitae, auctor non, suscipit at, ipsum. Cras varius sapien vel lectus.</p>

            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="widget color-red">  
            <div class="widget-head">
                <h3>Widget title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-content">
                <p id="persisted-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aliquam magna sem, fringilla in, commodo a, rutrum ut, massa. Donec id nibh eu dui auctor tempor. Morbi laoreet eleifend dolor. Suspendisse pede odio, accumsan vitae, auctor non, suscipit at, ipsum. Cras varius sapien vel lectus.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

And the JS:

```
    var supported = 'This text will be saved locally, forever.',
      unsupported = 'Oh no! Your browser does not support localStorage.';
  if (window.localStorage) {
      var p = document.querySelector('#persisted-text');
      if (localStorage.text == null) {
          localStorage.text = p.value = supported;
      } else {
          p.value = localStorage.text;
      }
      p.addEventListener('keyup', function(){ localStorage.text = p.value; }, false);
  } else {
      document.getElementById('persisted-text').value = unsupported;
  }
```

This works too, if I create a textarea and add the id, however it only works for one of the areas. I would ideally like the combination of both these (editable and localstorage), if possible. What am I missing?

I also loaded a jsfiddle of this http://jsfiddle.net/6LdfD/2/

Thanks for looking

Comment: you can't use same id more than once in document, use class please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is several problems with your code,

1. multiple ids, it is not allowed by html standard
2. you can't set keyup/input events on contendeditable childrens,
3. instead of 'value' you have to change innerText property of the node.

so here is demo with minimal changes to your code (please note that i not make best for paragrpah index (just in order of appear)

html:

```
<div id="columns">
    <ul id="column1" class="column">
        <li class="widget color-red" id="edit1">
            <div class="widget-head">
                 <h3>Widget title</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="widget-content">
                <p class="persisted-text" contenteditable="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aliquam magna sem, fringilla in, commodo a, rutrum ut, massa. Donec id nibh eu dui auctor tempor. Morbi laoreet eleifend dolor. Suspendisse pede odio, accumsan vitae, auctor non, suscipit at, ipsum. Cras varius sapien vel lectus.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="widget color-red">
            <div class="widget-head">
                 <h3>Widget title</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="widget-content">
                <p class="persisted-text" contenteditable="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aliquam magna sem, fringilla in, commodo a, rutrum ut, massa. Donec id nibh eu dui auctor tempor. Morbi laoreet eleifend dolor. Suspendisse pede odio, accumsan vitae, auctor non, suscipit at, ipsum. Cras varius sapien vel lectus.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

js

```
  var supported = 'This text will be saved locally, forever.',
      unsupported = 'Oh no! Your browser does not support localStorage.';
  if (window.localStorage) {
      var ps = document.querySelectorAll('.persisted-text');
      //localStorage.text=localStorage.text||[];
      for (var n = 0; n < ps.length; n++) {
          var p = ps[n];
          if (localStorage['text' + n] === undefined) {
              localStorage['text' + n] = p.innerText = supported;
          } else {
              p.innerText = localStorage['text' + n];
          }
          console.log(p);
          document.addEventListener('input', (function (p, n) {
              return function (e) {
                  console.log(e, "111");
                  localStorage['text' + n] = p.innerText;
              };
          })(p, n));
      }
  } else {
      var ps = document.getElementsByClassName('persisted-text');
      for (var n = 0; n < ps.length; n++) {
          var p = ps[n];
          p.innerText = unsupported;
      }
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6LdfD/5/

Answer (score 1):

In my demo, I am selecting all of the elements that are `p` and have `contenteditable`. You could also use a class to identify the elements that you want this to work with. I'm associating the elements with their data based on their location on the page, so the first `<p contenteditable="true"></p>` tag is associated with `localStorage['editable0']`. This could be problematic if you move the markup around, so you may want to put a marker (class or data-attribute) on each element and use that to identify each element. This should get you started and you can expand on it and adapt it to your needs.

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/UweJOjax/2/edit)

```
var editables = document.querySelectorAll('p[contenteditable]');

for (var i=0; i<editables.length; ++i) {
  var prop = 'editable'+i;
  if (localStorage[prop]) { //restore content from cache if it exists
    editables[i].textContent = localStorage[prop];
  }
  addKeyup(editables[i], prop);
}

function addKeyup(elem, prop) {
  elem.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    store(prop, this.textContent); 
  }); 
}

function store(prop, val) {
  localStorage[prop] = val;
  console.log(prop);
  console.log(localStorage[prop]);
}
```

and your markup could look like:

```
  <p contenteditable="true">Some text.</p>
  <p contenteditable="true">Some text.</p>
  <p contenteditable="true">Some text.</p>
  <p contenteditable="true">Some text.</p>
  <p contenteditable="true">Some text.</p>
```